# sql: check for existence of only one specific item for an id, when multiple items may exist

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, exists

I have a database of locations that can have anywhere from 0 to 27 types of logs available. I'm only interested in the presence of 1 type of log and want to return true or false if that log exists. I tried using CASE WHEN but the problem is my results are showing true or false if the one log exists (which is the desired outcome)and then false for all of the other logs, so I get multiple rows with the same id (which is not what I want). 
Sample code:

```
SELECT
Table1.LocationId
, CASE WHEN Table2.LogId = 8 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS 'Log8Avail'
```

Desired result would be:

```
| LocationID |Log8Avail|
 ----------------------
| 1          | True    |
 ----------------------
| 2          | False   |
 ----------------------
| 3          | True    |
 ----------------------
```

But what I'm currently getting is:

```
| LocationId | Log8Avail|
 -----------------------
| 1          | True     |
 ----------------------- 
| 1          | False    |
 -----------------------
| 1          | False    |
 -----------------------
| 2          | False    |
 -----------------------
```

My question is, how can I adjust my query so that it only looks for the presence or absence of the specific log I'm interested in?

Comment: Please show your full query.  Where is `Table2.LogId` coming from?  What are your table definitions?  Also, what DBMS are you using?  (MySQL?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  Something else?)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new to StackFlow and SQL. Next time I will post full code and specify the DBMS. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.LocationId, 
       CASE WHEN t2.LogID IS NULL 
            THEN false 
            ELSE TRUE 
       END as Log8Avail
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
      ON t1.id = t2.id
     AND t2.LogId = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Table1.LocationId
, CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM Table2 
             WHERE Table2.LogId = 8)>0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' 
  END AS 'Log8Avail'
```

Like this?